# How does the return statement work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, return, console.log

So, I am a beginner in JavaScript and I was just playing around by creating some functions!
why does if returned there is a different answer and why does if console logged there is a different answer!

SO IF I CONSOLE LOG THIS

```js
const ex = (arra1) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arra1.length; i++) {
    console.log(arra1[i]);
  }
};
ex([1, 2, 3]);
```

answer for the above function is `1 2 3`

BUT IF RETURN THIS

```js
const ex = (arra1) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arra1.length; i++) {
    return arra1[i];
  }
};
console.log(ex([1, 2, 3]));
```

But the answer for this above function is `1`

Comment: `return` immediately terminates the function execution, so you only get one iteration from the loop.

Comment: `return` will terminate the function execution,  thus it terminates the loop aswell

Comment: There's always good reading on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Answer (score 1):

`return` will stop the execution immediately. As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return),

> When a return statement is used in a function body, the execution of the function is stopped. If specified, a given value is returned to the function caller.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you are not returning anything but just logging the each value of the array.

```
console.log(arra1[i]);
```

In the second example you are just using return in the loop so in the first iteration the function will return a value which is first element of array. `return` statement just ends the further execution of the function.

Answer (score 1):

`return` terminates the function and the loop, stopping after the first iteration

In the first example you don't terminate anything, so you end up iterating over everything